# Magento 1.9.2.1 add to cart button redirects to empty cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have update the magento version from 1.8 to 1.9.2.1. Now the add to cart button from home page redirect to empty cart.

The add to cart button code is as follow:

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')"
```

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: On which page are you trying above code?

Comment: I have used it at home page.

Comment: load product by id and assign that to the **$product**............something like below `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)`

Comment: Yes Ramesh Kumar. I have done in the same way.
 Issue comes at  I think `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.php::_validateFormKey() `.
`$form_key and Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ` does not matched and return false.

Comment: check forms on formskey exits or not. if not added please add
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: At home page as there is no form.

Answer (score 2):

Please check form key on the URL it is adding or not, because in magento 1.9 higher version need form key for adding product to cart.
as like..

setLocation('http://domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEwLjAuNC40L21hZ2VudG8vbWFnZW50bzEuOS9pbmRleC5waHAvYWNjZXNzb3JpZXMvZXlld2Vhci5odG1s/product/338/**form_key/7GpQmuCT2ybnEVoh/**')

Comment: Yes. form key adding to the url. Here is the Url : http://domain.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuZmxvd2VyY3JlYXRpb25zLmNhLw,,/product/1237/form_key/GTA7nkHzRo5tyo1B/

Comment: Its working from home page. But not working from home page. At view page form submitted and its working.

Comment: ok , than please use form as like related product functionality....I hope it will work..

Comment: How to use form at home page??

Comment: <form action="addtocart">
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>
<input type="hidden" value="product id" name="product"/>
<submit button >
</form>

Comment: I have added the form. Actually issue comes when I clear the browser cache or visit first time to the site. If I visit any other page and come back to home page. It still not add to cart.

Comment: Check your cart request after submitting form in controller ......check line by line......in controller .......

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with caching the New Products Block. Put cache_lifetime="1" at the end of the calling block in CMS page like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" cache_lifetime="1"}}
```

. It basicly tells Magento to never chache this module.